# Alternative to 'self = this' with object in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this code:

```
function Person(name){      
    var self = this;

    this.name = name;

    function hello(){
        alert("hello " + self.name);
    }

    return {
        hello: hello
    };
}

var newPerson = new Person("john");

newPerson.hello();
```

I want to be able to use the 'this' keyword to access the 'name' property in the 'hello' function; I want an alternative to using the 'self' variable.

Except using the $.proxy function of jquery to control the context, how can I write the same code but without the variable 'self'?

I want a code that looks like below but 'name' is always 'undefined' when I call 'newPerson.hello()'. I don't know why because I have always believed that the scope of a function is always the object at the left of the dot of the caller and in this case, it's 'newPerson' that have been assign a value 'john' when creating the object.

```
function Person(name){              
    this.name = name;

    function hello(){
        alert("hello " + this.name);
    }

    return {
        hello: hello
    };
}

var newPerson = new Person("john");

newPerson.hello();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use return by default when using the `new` keyword the function will return `this`
you will need to change how your function is declared how ever.

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SaintGerbil/9SAhD/

```
function Person(name){              
    this.name = name;
    this.hello = function (){
        alert("hello " + this.name);
    }
}

var newPerson = new Person("john");

newPerson.hello();​
```

**EDIT** if you require name to be private then here is an alternative

```
function Person(name){              
    var _name = name;
    this.hello = function (){
        alert("hello " + _name);
    }
}

var newPerson = new Person("john");

newPerson.hello();​
```

In answer to your question there are 4 ways to call a function
These affect the value of `this` they are

- Constructor call (using the `new` keyword) where `this` is the new object which is returned automatically.
- Method call if a function is attached to an object and called from it then `this` is the object called from.
- Function call a direct call to a function will result in `this` being the global object, (a common mistake when calling a contstructor without new)
- Apply\Call call when using a method to specify what this should be (see jackwanders as an example)

**FURTHER EDIT**

So taking your desired code at the start and explaining what is happening.

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name; // 1

    function hello(){ // 2
        alert("hello " + this.name); // 3
    } 

    return {
        hello: hello
    }; //4
}
```

Person as a function *can* be called two ways:

`var x = Person("ted");`

and

`var x = new Person("jimmy");`

Since you have named Person with a capital it implies that you are expecting people to use `new`.
So sticking with that we enter the function and javascript  creates a new object and assigns it to `this`.

- *line 1* we then attach a 'name' variable to `this` and initialise with the passed parameter.
- *line 2* we then attach a 'hello' function to `this`.
- *line 3* the function expects to have a 'name' variable exist attached to this (which it does for now).
- *line 4* rather than return `this` (default behavior) we are now declaring a new object and attaching the function to it. This new object does not have a 'name' variable with in its scope.

So when you create the object you get an object with a function attached but it cannot get to the variable it needs to execute correctly. 
Which is why you are getting the undefined.

Does that make sense I always worry that I'm waffling when I have to expand the textbox?

Or if I wrote out your function as verbosely as possible it would look something like this.

```
function Person(name){
  var this = new Object();
  this.name = name;
  var hello = function (){
    alert("hello " + this.name);
  } 
  this.hello = hello;

  var that = new Object();
  that.hello = hello;

  return that;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After reading your example, what I understand is when you assign the function to a variable using 'this', you forcing the function to use the 'this' of the context of the constructor of the object and after you call the function of the object, 'this' will always be the 'this' when the object have been constructed. Am I right?

Comment: @Samuel's way of writing `Person` is valid; it is called a *"durable object"*. In his function, `.name` becomes 'private' to the constructor. In your function, `.name` is publicly accessible.

Comment: @Samuel Yes when you call a function with `new` `this` refers to the object being created. when you call a function which is on an object it will call it as a method meaning that `this` will refer to the object. What you were doing was declaring one object and returning another (with a hello function in).

Comment: @jackwanders I'm aware of the "durable object" pattern I would say if you need to have name become private then declare that as a variable rather than attaching to `this`.

Comment: @Saint Gerbi Thank you very much. I now understand that my original object have a function defined that when not assigned to the object with 'this.functionName = ...' each time I will call the function, javascript will returns a new function and in this case, 'this' will refer to the global window and this is why 'name' is 'undefined'. Am I right?

Comment: Not quite I've expanded my answer in order to try and simplify the problem.

Comment: Wow, much much than what I've read from a great books. Thank you very much for the deep explanation.

Comment: Just to go a little bit further,  if javascript  create a new object behind the scenes when I return the hello function like in my case #2 and this is the reason why I cannot access the variable name,  why in the first case when I assign this to variable self,  I can access the variable name?  Is this because of the same rules that makes possible closure?  Thank you again for your time,, it's very appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.bind` to force the owner of a function to be whatever object you pass. So, you can write your `Person` object like so:

```
function Person(name){ 
    this.name = name;

    var hello = function(){
        alert("hello " + this.name);
    }.bind(this);

    return {
        hello: hello
    };
}
```

This will ensure that `.hello` always executes in the context of the `Person` that is calling it.

Here's a demo:

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/mhJ4f/)

Comment: Should be accepted answer , according to question .

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be confusing two things.

## a) Regular functions

```
function CreatePerson(name) {
    // create a new object
    var person = {};
    // or (if you want to provide a prototype)
    var person = Object.create(...);

    // fill it with some more data
    person.name = name;
    person.foo = 123;
    person.bar = function() { /* ... your method body ... */ }; 
}
```

That's invoked like:

```
var person = CreatePerson("Jack");
```

## b) Constructors

```
function Person(name) {
    // called after a Person is created,
    // `this` is bound to the new object
    // and its prototype is set to `Person.prototype`

    this.name = name;
    this.foo = 123;
    this.bar = function() { /* ... your method body ... */ }; 
}

var person = new Person("Jack");
```

Note the special `new` syntax here.

When using this style, you'll probably want to create the methods only once, not for every created instance:

```
function Person(name) {
    // called after a Person is created,
    // `this` is bound to the new object
    // and its prototype is set to `Person.prototype`

    this.name = name;
    this.foo = 123;
}
Person.prototype.bar = function() {
    /* ... your method body ... */
};

var person = new Person("Jack");
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing like this works.

If you only want to access the this within the function you can do like this.
you use the return {hello:hello} to declare the function and you don't need do to it, unless it's what you want

example 1

> ```
>        function _persons(array) {
>           this.available = array;
>           this.write = function () {
>               writedata(this.available, '#array2');
>           };
>           this.SortAge = function () {
>               array.sort(compare);
>               writedata(this.available, '#array3');
>           };
>           array.sort(compareName);
>       } 
>      var users = new _persons(myarray);
> ```

example 2

> ```
>   function Person(name ){
>        this.name = name ;
>         this.hello = function(){
>         alert("hello " + this.name);
>         }
>       }
>
>       var a = "john";
>       var newPerson = new Person(a); 
>       newPerson.hello(); var
>       otherPerson = new Person("annie"); 
>       otherPerson.hello();
> ```

Comment: this doesn't appear to be a solution to this person's question. Did you accidentally post in the wrong question?

Comment: It was an example. he can access the this propriety with my example.